# Counterexample(?) of the theorem An Orthonormal basis of a vector space X is a Hamel basis if and only if X is finite dimensional.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, orthonormal, hamel-basis

I found somewhere the following theorem.

*An Orthonormal basis of a vector space X is a Hamel basis if and only if X is finite dimensional.*

For Hilbert spaces it is quite easy to prove but for pre-Hilbert spaces I'm not really sure that this is true.

As a counterexample, the basis $(e_i)$ where each sequence $e_i$ is defined as $e_i^{(k)}=\delta_{ki}$ is an orthonormal-Hamel basis in $c_{00}$ with the inner product $||\cdot||_2$, but the space $c_{00}$ is not finite dimensional.

Where am I wrong? I know in some books they define Orthonormal basis in Hilbert spaces, but in my definition they can also exist in pre-Hilbert spaces. Is that the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, one needs completeness for the conclusion. In every Hilbert space $H$, the subspace spanned by an ONB is one where the ONB is also a Hamel basis. But that subspace is closed if and only if $H$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: Assuming $c_{00}$ is the space of sequences that are eventually zero you're not wrong, this is all correct. If you really read that theorem stated for _vector spaces_ $X$ then now you know you can't believe everything you read.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is infinite dimensional, then it possesses an orthonormal basis $\mathscr B$, which is clearly infinite dimensional (Zorn's Lemma is required to prove it).

We shall show that $\mathscr B$ is NOT a Hamel basis.

Let $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset\mathscr B$ be an orthonormal sequence and 
$$
w=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}e_k.
$$
It can be readily shown that the $w$ is perpendicular (and hence linearly independent) to 
the elements of
$\mathscr B\!\smallsetminus\!\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and linearly independent with the elements of $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$.

In the same way one can construct $2^{\aleph_0}$ such elements.